# DataGridView Save Changes On Row Change

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am attempting to save a record after leaving the row in a `DataGridView`.

I have seen solutions use the `RowValidated` event, however, when the rows are sorted then the record gets resorted before the `RowValidation` event is fired. I also attempted to get the row using the `BindingSource` Current property, but the current property is already changed. Same applies to RowLeaving I believe.

I have tried using the `RowChanged` event on the datatable directly and that does work OK.

I ended up using the `RowValidation` event and getting the changes from the datatable (`GetChange())`, but this doesn’t seem idea.

In addition for deletes I used the `UserDeletingRow` event, but again this doesn’t seem idea.

What is the best way for saving records after leaving the row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you taken a look at `.RowLeave`?

```
private void dataGridView1_RowEnter(object sender, 
    DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells.Count; i++)
    {
        dataGridView1[i, e.RowIndex].Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
    }
}

private void dataGridView1_RowLeave(object sender, 
    DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells.Count; i++)
    {
        dataGridView1[i, e.RowIndex].Style.BackColor = Color.Empty;
    }
}
```

source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowleave.aspx

Comment: Doesn't seem to contain the changes during `RowLeave`.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried the [`DataGridView.RowValidating Event`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowvalidating.aspx) and [`.IsCurrentRowDirty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.iscurrentrowdirty.aspx)?

```
    private void dataGridView1_RowValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.IsCurrentRowDirty)
        {
           //Do stuff
        }
    }
```